# How do I change the viewColumnHeader in Xpage?

Tags: xpages

I want to change the view column header's value in Xpage...

I have used the following code

```
getComponent("viewColumnHeader1").setValue("Test")
```

But the above code throws the `getComponent() is null` error...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is correct but the problem is probably in where you've placed it.

Just performed a quick test and the code works if you place it in the afterPageLoad event of an XPage containing the view/ header.

Comment: I set a default value for an Edit box... Now also I am getting the same Error... I am using 8.5.2., Here the above code is not working...

Answer (score 2):

Why not just compute the "Label" property for column header to begin with:

```
<xp:viewColumn columnName="fldTest" id="viewColumn1">
            <xp:viewColumnHeader value="testing" id="viewColumnHeader1"></xp:viewColumnHeader>
        </xp:viewColumn>
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Okay Nice, It is working... Thanks But Why we are not able to get that viewColumnHeader value...

Comment: This works for me in 8.5.3 not sure about 8.5.2 - try this (as Mark suggested): <xp:this.afterPageLoad><![CDATA[#{javascript:getComponent("viewColumnHeader1").setValue("new heading");}]]></xp:this.afterPageLoad> - hope this helps.